# Laravel 8 database connection not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Trying to connect laravel 8 app in production to mysql database. Have tried to follow documentation but it isn't working.

.env file as follows

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=domain_laravelapp
DB_USERNAME=domain_admin
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

config/database.php as follows

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('domain.co.uk:3306'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('domain_laravelapp', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('domain_admin', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('password', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

when i run `php artisan migrate --force`, i get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = forge and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:678
    674▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    675▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    676▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    677▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 678▕             throw new QueryException(
    679▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    680▕             );
    681▕         }
    682▕

      +33 vendor frames
  34  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

Can anybody please explain what I'm going wrong?

It seems to be ignoring both those files.

Comment: Why have you edited the config file? you should not do that, at most you should change the default value, but not the rest...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write in terminal :

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work for you, database, username and password will come from .env so you don't need to change it.

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('domain.co.uk:3306'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing an environment variable named `password`.

The error message tells you that no password could be found: `Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`, "using password: NO" being the interesting part.